# Tagging something with [windows] and [windows-10]

Tags: discussion

[Referencing this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1210267/cmd-window-quickly-opens-and-closes), the community at large approved my edit. I removed the [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag from the question, and replaced it with with [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10). Later on, another user edit was made, adding [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) back to the question.

Is this not redundant? It's not really a problem per say, and in the long run it doesn't matter. But should questions pertaining to Windows be tagged with their specific operating system, and the general [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no *need* for both.

The [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag is meant:

> For questions not specific to a single version of Microsoft Windows. Otherwise, use a more specific tag such as [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) or [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).

Having said that, I would not normally have removed it when adding a version specific tag like [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) as it does not cause any harm and allows someone to easily find all questions about Windows using a tag search.

The exception to that would be a case where there were already 5 tags (5 is the maximum number of allowed tags). Then I would remove [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) to leave space for [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).

I probably wouldn't have made an edit that only added [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) back in to the question.

Comment: Works for me, just wanted to double check on it. Thanks!

Comment: You can search for "windows*", so having both doesn't help search.

Comment: @Braiam Oh. I never realised you could use wildcards in tag searches ...

Comment: Note that the edit that added (windows) back to the question didn’t do *only* that; it also made a minor grammatical correction and spelled out an abbreviation.  But there’s another issue: if you have a total score of 60 in the (windows-7) tag and a 40 score in the (windows-10) tag, that’s not enough to earn the bronze badge for the (windows) tag (or is it?). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … There’s a difference between questions that are specifically *about* Windows 10, and questions that are about Windows (in general) but have been posted by somebody who is using Windows 10.  Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar, and sometimes a Windows question is just a Windows question, requiring only general knowledge of Windows.  Don’t we want to be able to keep track of our generalist Windows experts, and use badges to identify (and reward) them?

Comment: @Scott Additionally, it could be hard to tell, whether something is a problem pertaining only to a specific version of Windows, or is it something that is shared between several versions.